# Python find string in file, edit line and save to a new file

Tags: python, string, find, save, edit

I'm trying to go through a text file and find all the lines that start with 'file='. When I find these lines I want to remove all the text in between the dots and finally save that as a new file.

Such lines look like so

> file="image.&!145.jpg"

I'm currently stuck to the place where I either:

- delete the text between dots all over the file (not just the lines that start with 'file=')
- delete the text between the dots only on the lines that start with 'file=', but I only end up saving that single line in the new document.

Here's the code that I have so far:

```
import os
from os.path import basename
from re import sub


file_in = 'tex_file_01.txt'
file_out = 'tex_file_01_new.txt'


with open(file_in, 'r') as f_in:
    with open(file_out, 'w') as f_out:
        for line in f_in:
            if 'file=' in line:
                print 'found: ' + line

            line_fix = sub('\..*?\.', '.', line)
            print 'fixed: ' + line_fix

            f_out.write(line.replace(line, line_fix))
```

The above piece of code deletes the text between the dots all over the file.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

Comment: did you try adding `line_fix = sub('\..*?\.', '.', line)` in the `IF` statement itself rather than writing it outside ?

Comment: Quick look would suggest you just need to indent the lines after the `if` so that they are only done when you find a line of interest, *then* append an `else: f_out.write(line))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this out. The only error I see is that portion which comes in the if condition. You are editing all lines of the file.

```
import os
from os.path import basename
from re import sub


file_in = 'tex_file_01.txt'
file_out = 'tex_file_01_new.txt'


with open(file_in, 'r') as f_in:
    with open(file_out, 'w') as f_out:
        for line in f_in:
            if 'file=' in line:
                print('found: ' + line)
                line_fix = sub('\..*?\.', '.', line)
            else:
                line_fix = line
            print('fixed: ' + line_fix)
            
            f_out.write(line.replace(line, line_fix))
```